# Django: Cannot access _meta of model class in same model file

Tags: django, django-models

I have **Plant** model and a method ***get_plant_measurement_field_details*** returning Plant fields starting with *'measurement'* so that i can use its name and verbose name for creating another model named **PlantModelMeasurementRange**

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(PlantModel, null=True, blank=True)
    measurement_outlet_length = models.FloatField(
        verbose_name=_('Outlet length in cm'),
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    measurement_outlet_width = models.FloatField(
        verbose_name=_('Outlet width in cm'),
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )


def get_plant_measurement_field_details():
    fields = Plant._meta.get_fields()
    measurement_field_details = []
    for field in fields:
        if field.name.startswith('measurement'):
            measurement_field_details.append(
                {
                    'name': field.name,
                    'verbose_name': field.verbose_name
                }
            )
    return measurement_field_details

class PlantModelMeasurementRange(models.Model):
    model = models.OneToOneField(PlantModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='range')

for field in get_plant_measurement_field_details()[0]:
    models.FloatField(
        verbose_name='Maximum Value of %s' % 
field.get('verbose_name').lower()
    ).contribute_to_class(
        PlantModelMeasurementRange, '%s_max' % field.get('name').lower()
    )
```

But on runserver it thorows following exception:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Is there any better way to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what the goal is without thinking about the implementation? So, what are measurement ranges to plants?

Comment: As you can see **Plant** class has field *model* which is fk with **PlantModel**. I need to define max and min value for each measurement field for each  **PlantModel**

Comment: Without thinking about implementation means you don't use words like "model", "field" and "foreign key". I think your data model is overly complicated but for that I need to know what these models *represent* in the real world. I understand you want to restrict ranges of the measurements, but there's no way to "fetch something from the database to generate declarations for another model". So that road is a dead end and to be able to come up with alternative, I need to relate this to what it represents.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.